# UnsupportedOnDevError: Matching to field type of field "location" (type=5) is unsupported on dev server

Tags: google-app-engine

Has anyone tried doing simple query using search service where the documents to query against have a `GeoField`? I did, my query has only text like 'John Doe' to match against and it seems the dev server try to match the query text against every single fields including the geo field. And it just throws that error, and seem there are no way to exclude geo fields out of it.

Will the production server behaves this way also? How can I tell it to query against every fields but the geo fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev server has poor support for GeoFields at the moment, but in production it works as you'd expect. It sounds like you've found a bug, though; just having a GeoField on a document shouldn't cause your queries to fail. [I've filed a bug for you here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8315) -- if you star it, you'll get notifications when it's fixed.

As a workaround, if you know what field that you want to find the text in, you can use "myfield:john myfield:doe", which will prevent the error from happening. Alternatively, you could put in logic to not include the GeoFields when you index documents if it's running locally.

Comment: In production, having a GeoField in my document is fine then? Are you sure?

Comment: Yup, completely sure. (Check my bio :)

Comment: I have reproduced this without a global term search (by specifying a field). Comment and more info added to the bug.